# I want to await a function to complete then run another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, es6-promise

This is the code I am trying with:

```js
const arr = ['a' , 'b' ,'c', 'd']

const func = async () => {
    let i = 0
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        let x = arr[i++ % arr.length]
        console.log(x)
        if (i === 4 ) {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, 2000)
}

const another_func = () => {
    console.log('logic')
}

const main = async () => {
    await func()
    another_func()
}
main()
```

Output :-

```
logic
a
b
c
d
```

When I run this problem "logic" gets printed before all the elements of array.

Why should I do print all the elements of array first and only then run the other function and print the logic?

Comment: You should explicitly return a promise, then call the callback on the fourth interval.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need to use Promise. Here is my solution:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

const func = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let i = 0
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        let com = arr[i++ % arr.length]
        console.log(com)
        if (i === 4) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve('success');
        }
    }, 2000)
})

const another_func = () => {
    console.log('logic')
}

const main = async () => {
    await func()

    another_func()
}
main()
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with my solution, please accept this answer by checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `async` function doesn't use `await`, which is already a sign of a problem. `setInterval` schedules the execution of the callback, but the `setInterval` call itself immediately returns, so your `async` function returns, and the implicit promise it returns is resolved. So `main` is awaiting a promise that is immediately resolved.

You can typically get a correct implementation by *promisifying* `setTimeout`, i.e. you define a helper function that returns a promise which will resolve after a given delay. With that in place you can create a `for` loop with `await` in the first `async` function:

```js
// Helper function that promisifies setTimeout
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const arr = ['a' , 'b' ,'c', 'd'];

const func = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        await delay(1000);
        let x = arr[i % arr.length];
        console.log(x);
    }
}

const another_func = () => {
    console.log('logic');
}

const main = async () => {
    await func();
    another_func();
}
main();
```